# #Oracle#PL/SQL:Substitution variables for multiple inputs

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I want to take input from the user multiple times and for that I am using substitution variable but unable to get the desired output.I am expecting oracle to ask the user for input multiple times depending upon the looping conditions.For example,

```
    declare
    names varchar2(100);

    begin
    for j in 1..3 loop
    names:='&i';
    dbms_output.put_line(j ||names);
    end loop;

    end;
    /
```

----------------------Output-----------------

```
 1jack
 2jack
 3jack
```

Kindly suggest some alternative for the same.

Comment: The phrasing in the first sentence is a bit confusing.

Comment: You can't reasonably.  PL/SQL has no facility to prompt users for input.  That has to be done by the client application.  SQL*Plus has a very limited facility to prompt for input and it doesn't have a facility to code a loop.  You could build a very unusual/ complicated SQL*Plus script that would simulate a loop but it would be vastly easier to write a batch file/ shell script/ perl script/ something else that prompted for input and sent queries to the database.

Comment: @ppperry : If I run this block Oracle will ask the user to give an input and that value will be stored in the variable names and will be displayed thrice in the above case.I want oracle to ask the user to give an input thrice so that different names can be printed.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use parameter list as collection constructor parameter. You can't possibly input the values one by one but all at once.

```
HUSQVIK@orcl> DECLARE
  2     TYPE t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
  3     names t := t(&names);
  4  BEGIN
  5      FOR j IN 1..names.COUNT LOOP
  6             dbms_output.put_line(j || names(j));
  7      END LOOP;
  8  END;
  9  /
Enter value for names: 'Jack', 'Niels', 'Tom'
1Jack
2Niels
3Tom

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: when I am running the above code I am getting the following error
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 28:
PLS-00302: component 'COUNT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 3, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Strange. Which Oracle version are you using? You can also use `FOR j IN 1..names.LAST LOOP` it's no difference in this case.

Comment: I am using oracle 12C , I am getting an error identifier 'Jack' must be declared

Comment: I am getting the same error for the updated code,
PLS-00201 : error: identifier 'Jack' must be declared   and
PLS-00320 : error : The declaration of type this expression is incomplete or malformed

Comment: Use `Enter value for names: 'Jack', 'Niels', 'Tom'` for parameter NOT `Enter value for names: Jack, Niels, Tom`